# Can I use plotly figure factory offline in python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I'm trying to create a gantt chart with plotly in an offline Jupyter notebook, mashing together the [Gantt chart tutorial](https://plot.ly/python/gantt/) and the [offline tutorial](https://plot.ly/python/offline/), I tried this:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

dfoo = [dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
      dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15'),
      dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30')]
fig = ff.create_gantt(dfoo)
py.iplot(fig)
```

But this only returns an error about the plotly API, which shouldn't happen if I'm offline...

```
PlotlyRequestError: Aw, snap! You tried to use our API as the user ___, but the supplied API key doesn't match our records.
```

I can plot other charts offline, is there a way to use figure factory and plot offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, shoot, it was a very simple mistake.

`py.iplot(fig)` calls the online version of plotly while `iplot(fig)` calls the offline version.

This works for me

```
dfoo = [dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
      dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15'),
      dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30')]
fig = ff.create_gantt(dfoo)
iplot(fig)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `plotly.offline.plot(fig)` if you `import plotly`, it doesn't work for 'plotly.plotly' though.